# What is the difference between gross weight and MTOW in an aircraft specification?

Tags: takeoff, terminology, weight

On Wikipedia you often find aircraft specified with a separate "gross weight" and "MTOW". The term "gross weight" implies "weight with maximum fuel and payload". Yet this is not the case, since the MTOW is given separately.

I tried googling 'gross weight Vs MTOW" and got this.

- Gross Takeoff Weight: The weight of the airplane just before brake
  release to begin the takeoff roll.
- Useful Load: The weight of crew, cargo, passengers, baggage, and
  usable fuel.
- Maximum Ramp Weight (MRW): The maximum weight for ground operations.
- Maximum Takeoff Weight (MTOW): The maximum weight for takeoff.

As you can see, not only is the term "Gross Weight" not used directly, but the term that *is* used has a definition that isn't particularly helpful in this context.

Comment: Not sure where you found this definition: "gross weight" implies "weight with maximum fuel.amd payload". That is certainly not the correct definition.

Comment: Sounds like a Wikipedia problem to me.  If I'm reading a "Gross Weight" value in a Wikipedia entry I would *tend* to think they are probably giving the max allowed Gross Weight, although they really should say so explicitly.  As far as splitting hairs between max ramp weight and max takeoff weight,  I dunno.  Basically, if you are giving one single number for "Gross Weight" without any further explanation, then you are not being very precise in your terminology.  As to why that number should be different from MTOW or MRW, who knows.  Which is usually given as the higher number, GW or MTOW?

Comment: (In your linked B-29 example MTOW was the higher number, noted as "combat overload", so maybe the GW number is some sort of original *designed* max TOW or RW?)

Answer (score 4):

The **gross weight** is the *current* total weight of the aircraft. It is basically the value a scale would show when putting the aircraft on it. It obviously changes all the time, e.g. when payload (passengers or cargo) is loaded/unloaded or when the aircraft if refueled and also during the flight as fuel is burned.

The **Maximum Takeoff Weight (MTOW)** is a legal *limitation* given by the aircraft manufacturer. It is the highest value for the gross weight at which the aircraft is certified to take off. When the gross weight is higher than MTOW, you are not allowed to take off.

References:

- [SKYbrary: Maximum Take-Off Mass (MTOM)](https://skybrary.aero/articles/maximum-take-mass-mtom)
- [Wikipedia: Aircraft gross weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_gross_weight)

Comment: Then why on earth is it specified at a certain value?

Comment: @AbdullahisnotanAmalekite Yeah, that doesn't make sense. Can you show an example? I looked at a few Wikipedia articles for aircraft specifications and couldn't find one that specifies gross weight.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-29_Superfortress

Comment: @AbdullahisnotanAmalekite That Wikipedia article uses [this NASA table](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/pao/History/SP-468/app-a2.htm) as a source. No idea what they mean with $w_g$. Maybe typical gross weight?

Comment: @Bianfable: the [full NASA report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19850023776) defines $w_g$ as "design gross weight". I suspect this is simply a fancy terminology for the maximum taxi weight

Comment: @sophit Thanks for the link! It could be a term for max. taxi weight as set during the initial design process. Wikipedia claims a higher MTOW though, so it may have changed during the development.

Comment: @sophit maximum taxi weight is greater than MTOW, whereas "gross weight" isnt

Comment: @AbdullahisnotanAmalekite: in the NASA report I linked, $w_g$ is the biggest weight, I was just referring to that specific report